# Java 11 : Cycle execute CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm looking a way to cycle CompletableFuture. Suppose I have

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hi");
 
future.thenApplyAsync(result -> {
    System.out.println(result + " all"); //output Hi all
    return result;
})
```

And I want to repeat this chain after it finished until I call cancel(). Is it possible? I can recreate this chain again in a for loop but it seems to be an ugly solution.

Comment: Why don't you put the cycle inside the Future? Then a single Future would be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, for loop would be ok but it doesn't seem an elegant solution. I'd like to implement some "transformToCycled()" function which would repeat this chain again. The chain itself could be much more complicated

Comment: How about having 2 Futures? One that performs a single operation and another, that implements a cycle by creating and Future of the 1st type and waiting for it?

Comment: Good point - thanks, please have a look at the solution if you are interested in

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `ScheduledExecutorService`, for instance `scheduleWithFixedDelay()`. You can put the logic executed by the current `Future` to the `Runnable`. If you don't needed any delay, you can set it to 0. From implementations I'd suggest to consider first the [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). If you want, you can override `shutdown()` and implement the desired shuddown logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mentallurg who provided a hint, I have developed the following solution

```
public class CombinedOperationsBuilder {
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<Void> transformToCycled(Supplier<CompletableFuture<T>> op)
    {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            for (;;) {
                try {
                    op.get().get();
                }catch (ExecutionException|InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not ignore exceptions!  Interrupts don’t happen by accident, so if someone interrupts your thread, it means they are asking you to *stop what you’re doing* and exit gracefully.  As for the ExecutionException, you should at least print its stack trace, so you can be aware when something goes wrong.

Comment: 1) At the beginning you said that doing an explicit cycle would be not elegant. Do you see that now elegant? :)  2) Why don't you use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay()`? You would avoid explicit cycle.  3) You wanted that it runs until cancel is requested. Now you ignore any cancel requests.